# Making unit test run as integration test instead

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have some projects with both unit tests and integration tests. I have them separated so that unit tests run as part of the regular build, and integration tests are only run by a specific "integTest" task. This is all working fine.

I have another project that I didn't write, and can't refactor, which has a single unit test that isn't really a unit test. I have a stock Gradle build script for this project, but I'd like to add the pieces that I put in other projects to run this test as an integration test instead. I haven't done this yet, but I think what I've done in other projects will only half work. I'm certain it will let me run that test as an integration test, but I don't yet know how to make it NOT run as a unit test.

The one test is in "src/test/java", and I'm now going to associate that with my "integTest" task (I used "src/integTest/groovy" before, and I imagine I could add "src/integTest/java" also). How do I REMOVE that directory from being considered by the default "test" task, so "test" never runs any tests?

**Update**:

Although the title of this posting is about running the unit test as an integration test, I really only needed to know how to exclude the existing test from the unit test pass, which was answered.

Someone seeing the title of this might want to know how to do that, so I'll add detail of how I did this.

The following shows everything that I added to the build script to make this happen:

```
// Without refactoring the source code of the project, this excludes the one test that looks like a unit test, but is
// actually an integration test.
test { exclude '**/*.*' }

sourceSets {
    integTest {
        java.srcDir file("src/test/java")
        resources.srcDir file("src/test/resources")
        runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
    }
}

dependencies {
    integTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
    integTestCompile configurations.testCompile
    integTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
    integTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime
}

task integTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir  = sourceSets.integTest.output.classesDir
    classpath       = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath
    // This forces integration tests to always run if the task is run.
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

Comment: You ask how to remove `src/test/java` from being considered as a default tests location?

Comment: Yes, as i want my integtest task to run it, not the default test task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build.gradle you can do:

`test {
    exclude '**/*.*'
}`

or just disable *test* task by adding the line `test.enabled = false`